# Referancing value from select column in where clause : Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

My tables are as below

**MS_ISM_ISSUE**

```
ISSUE_ID  ISSUE_DUE_DATE  ISSUE_SOURCE_TYPE
I1        25-11-2018      1
I2        25-12-2018      1
I3        27-03-2019      2
```

**MS_ISM_SOURCE_SETUP**

```
SOURCE_ID MODULE_NAME
1         IT-Compliance
2         Risk Assessment
```

I have written following query.

```
with rs as
(select 
count(ISSUE_ID) as ISSUE_COUNT, src.MODULE_NAME, 
case 
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE<sysdate then 'Overdue'
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE between sysdate and sysdate + 90 then 'Within 3 months'
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE>sysdate+90 then 'Beyond 90 days'
end as date_range
from MS_ISM_ISSUE issue, MS_ISM_SOURCE_SETUP src
where issue.Issue_source_type = src.source_id
group by src.MODULE_NAME, case 
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE<sysdate then 'Overdue'
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE between sysdate and sysdate + 90 then 'Within 3 months'
when ISSUE_DUE_DATE>sysdate+90 then 'Beyond 90 days'
end)  
select ISSUE_COUNT,MODULE_NAME, DATE_RANGE,
(select count(ISSUE_COUNT) from rs where rs.MODULE_NAME=MODULE_NAME) as total from rs;
```

The output of the code is as below.

```
ISSUE_COUNT  MODULE_NAME      DATE_RANGE     Total
1            IT-Compliance    Overdue           3
1            IT-Compliance    Within 3 months   3
1            Risk Assessment  Beyond 90 days    3
```

The result is correct till 3rd column. In 4th column what I want is, total of Issue count for given module name. Hence in above case Total column will have value as 2 for first and second row (since there are 2 Issues for IT-Compliance) and value 1 for the third row (since one issue is present for Risk Assessment).

Essentially, I want to achieve is to replace current row's MODULE_NAME in last where clause. How do I achieve this using query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this condition

```
where rs.MODULE_NAME=MODULE_NAME
```

is essentially the same as if you wrote

```
where MODULE_NAME = MODULE_NAME
```

which is simply always true (if there are no nulls in module_name).

Try using different table alias for inner query and outer query, e.g.

```
select count(ISSUE_COUNT) from rs rs2 where rs2.MODULE_NAME=rs.MODULE_NAME
```

You can also try to use [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) here, something like

```
select ISSUE_COUNT,
       MODULE_NAME,
       DATE_RANGE,
       COUNT(ISSUE_COUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY RS.MODULE_NAME) AS TOTAL
  from rs
```

instead of your subquery

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the help.Both of your methods work! Even I wanted to create two aliases for select statement within the with clause but couldn't think of any way of doing it. Its silly of me that I could not think of doing that in sub query :)